# Attach to Chrome instance and run JavaScript in a tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'd like to connect to an existing instance of Google Chrome and run some JavaScript to find a specific tab and execute some code in it.

I remember reading something about how to do this a long time ago.  Can anybody offer any guidance?

---

Edit: I've done this before using Firefox, and I just remembered I used the [MozRepl extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mozrepl/) there.

Comment: Just use the developer tools (F12) in the tab you want to execute in, then you could just put your code in the console screen

Comment: @DylanCorriveau no, this needs to be fully automatic.

Answer (score 0):

After remembering more about how I did this in the past with Firefox, it looks like the [ChromeRepl extension](https://github.com/kzys/chromerepl) may be the way to go here.

Comment: If this was the answer to it then, please be sure to accept your own answer (checkmark under the voting on this question)

Comment: Thanks.  I can't accept the answer for another 2 days.  I'd like to test it before then too.

Comment: Update after further research:  ChromeRepl uses an old debugging protocol that has now been removed.  The replacement protocol is https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugger-protocol.  Starting chrome with the `--remote-debugging-port=9222` option allows connecting via this protocol, but I'm still not sure what to do next.